# Splitting string as double array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, split, double, opentk

I have a problem : I have a string containing values and I want to split them into a double array .

The input : `0.0  0.0  0.0`

I have two ways but both are not working

First :

```
                Dim arrString As String() = line.Split(New Char() {" "c})
                Dim numbers As Double() = New Double(arrString.Length) {}
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                While i < arrString.Length
                    numbers(i) = Convert.ToDouble(arrString(i))
                    i += 1
                End While
```

Second :

```
                Dim nums As String() = line.Split(" "c)
                Dim numbers As Double() = From num In nums Select Convert.ToDouble(num)
```

I get a FormatExeption exeption
Please help me , its for an .obj loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current culture is likely using a different decimal separator. Use the overload of the `ToDouble` that takes a format provider:

```
Convert.ToDouble(num, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

(The `InvariantCulture` property returns a neutral culture info that is based on english settings, so it uses period as decimal separator.)

Comment: Sorry , I tried to msgbox the value of the line and it returned "v " instead of "0.0 0.0 0.0" , so the error comes from here :

For Each line As String In Lines
    If line.StartsWith("v ") Then
    line.Replace("v ", "")